# Ubuntu WiHotspot not running

Tags: hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I just got migrated from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTs and I could not use Wifi while sharing it at the same time. So I followed this tutorial with GPU and after I run, It prompts "Not Running"

https://www.makeuseof.com/create-wireless-hotspot-on-linux/

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your question with `iw list |grep "Supported interface modes:" -A10` to check if the wifi driver supporting the AP mode.